# ¿"No Mejorás." significa "Don't make it worse."?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Escuché que esta frase hablada con frecuencia como un comentario a una situación ya mala.
¿"No Mejorás". significa "Don't (try to) make it worse." en tal contexto?

Comment: Es voseo segunda persona singular del presente indicativo, (tú) no mejoras, (vos) no mejorás, you're not getting better, you are not making progress(continuous), you make no progress.

Comment: Como no practiques más, no mejorarás//If you don’t practice more, you won’t improve//Si no practicás/practicas más, no mejorarás//No vas a mejorar sin practicar//No vas a mejorar si no practicas/practicás más (Informal second-person sing. present indicative form of "practicar") también se puede conjugar en presente "mejorar".

Comment: I think the English idiom I would use is _You are not making it any better_ said to someone who is perhaps trying to help but inadvertently making things worse. As @cocteau states this is the use of the voseo form of the verb. We have a tag for that [tag:voseo] for more details.

Comment: En un contexto como el dado, sería más común oír: "Así no ayudás / no estás ayudando" (sino que estás empeorando las cosas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the provided context, it just means *you won't improve your situation* (by doing what you're doing or intend to do). However, this does not imply that the situation will become worse if the listener decides to do it or keeps doing it anyway, so we need more context for a proper translation.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con Nameless, pero creo que hay que diferenciar una **afirmación/crítica** de una **condición** (x implica ->y), es decir si hace algo eso tendrá/habrá consecuencias y de a cuando implica deseo, ansia o es algo que se está desarrollando, deseando o tratando de hacer (-ing) que también se conjuga como presente.

- "¡No *mejorás*!" (con el tiempo, debido a tu comportamiento, de acuerdo a los eventos) => "You're just the same as before", "You're not getting any further/better".
- (En el caso de que.., si .., si no.., como.., como no...[condición],  entonces ...): "Si no *mejorás*/mejoras, ¿Qué pasará?" => if you don't improve, then what? what will happen? // Cuando (*vos*/tú) sólo *hacés*/haces eso, entonces *mejorás*/mejoras/mejorarás/vas a mejorar sólo un poco"//Si *mejorás*/mejoras tu calidad de vida, *podés*/puedes lograr muchas más cosas//Si te tomaras/tomases las pastillas, (te, vos) mejorarías. <=> No te *tomás* las pastillas, y por eso no te *mejorás*/mejoras.
- (Cuando, en cuanto, mientras, en el momento... mejorás/mejorás/quieres mejorar/estás intentando mejorar ...)¿Por qué no te *mejorás*/mejoras vos lo antes posible, y te vas con ella?(X's condition hasn't improved")//"Cuando estás grave, y de repente te *mejorás*/mejoras"//Si *vos*/tú me *dijieses*/dijeras que *mejorás*/mejoras/estás mejorando/estás intentando mejorar/estás haciendo un esfuerzo por mejorar (yo) también te apoyaría//Si no *querés*/quieres cambiar tu vida y crecer como persona mientras *mejorás*/quieres mejorar/estás intentando mejorar al mundo, esto no es para ti/*vos*.
- No *ayudás* (a nadie) => "...what you're doing is not helping anyone".
- No *ayudás* (con lo que haces/dices) => You're not making it any better, no *hacés* ninguna diferencia.
- No ayuda (eso, -lo que+verb) => That's not helping anyone, it adds nothing to the case, it doesn't bring anything new, , no hace ninguna diferencia.
- No te ayuda => That doesn't help you.
- No te *ayudás* = > (do oneself no favors) you don't do yourself any favors with..